# Add an option in Settings to log out of a device that is logged in to your account

Tags: feature-request, security, logout

If someone is hacked/has a hacker running about in their account or just in general want to sign out on specific devices, having a list of devices currently logged in on the account under `My Logins` or a new tab, `Logged-In Devices`, and a button that says "End Session" at the side of that listing which logs out that device from your account.

I'm pretty sure Google and GitHub have this as a feature, so it'd be cool to see it on SO.

Comment: You don't have the option to logout on individual devices, but you do already have the option [to logout on _all_ devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PamIK.png).

Comment: But what if you don't want to log out on all devices because it'll log you out also.

Comment: Just log back in again.

Comment: But time is precious (*they* say...) so to save like 3 seconds of time, why not have a button to log out from certain devices?

Comment: Do you get hacked so often that your re-logging-in time is precious?

Comment: Well, if I've been logged out and been hacked then I won't be able to log in! I'm saying that if you spot the hacker before they do anything bad, you can kick them off.

Comment: Yes, GitHub positively has this feature (I was recently forced to change [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) system due to hardware problems). Even verification by email was required in that particular instance. Or maybe not this exact feature, but an email is send when logging in on a new device (as an alert) and a (second) verification email is also send as part of the process of logging in (supposedly to make it more difficult for a hacker) - the user name and password was not sufficient to log in (in that instance).